# Installation package for the ASP.NET web service

Tags: web-services, iis-7, windows-installer

I created an installation package for the web service. When I run the installer, it asks me to enter the web site name and application pool. I don't wan't to install the web service under existing web site. I'd like to place it under the root. Can I do something like that in Visual Studio?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) to package your app bundle into a zip package and then deploy it with a command line. It seems that Web Deploy might be a more suited technology than an msi as it gives you an easy support for parametrization and first hand access to IIS configuration (for your app deployment).

You can then use [manifest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569104%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider and define two separate app entries in it:

```
<MyPackage>
   <iisApp path="Default Web Site/MyApp" />
   <iisApp path="MyServicesSite" />
</MyPackage>
```

You can anything you want to the package using a manifest: an assembly to be added to the GAC, a registry key, the sky's the limit.

You then grab the manifest and package it:

`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:manifest="d:\manifest.xml" -dest:package="d:\mypackage.zip"`

And to deploy it by reversing a source and destination:

`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="d:\mypackage.zip" -dest:manifest="d:\manifest.xml"`

Or sync directly from a manifest to server:
`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:manifest="d:\manifest.xml" -dest:auto`